# How work with subquery in a View?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, view, subquery

I need create a **View** for this **Query**, *allowing change* **m.arq_data** and **m2.arq_data** values when a select uses this **View**, like:

```
select * FROM the_view WHERE m.arq_data = X AND m2.arq_data = Y
```

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT distinct(p.num_processo),p.num_proc_jud,a.assunto,su.subassunto,ma.Materia,u.Unidade ,M.COD_UNIDADE as cod_serv ,u.Unidade as servidor  ,' '  as serv_ativo,
'  '  as data_vinc ,' '  as  V_ativo, M.motivo,M.data_movimentacao as data_mov_distr ,
(select max(m2.arq_data)  from movimentacao m2 where  m2.arq_data 
BETWEEN '2011-08-01 00:00:00'AND '2011-08-31 23:00:00' and m2.num_processo =
  p.num_processo) as Data_Arq_Desarq , status = 'A'

--pra view
, M.arq_data

FROM processo p 
INNER JOIN assunto a ON a.cod_assunto  = p.cod_assunto  
INNER JOIN subassunto su ON su.cod_subassunto  = p.cod_subassunto
LEFT  JOIN materia ma ON ma.cod_materia  = p.cod_materia 
inner JOIN movimentacao M on M.num_processo = p.num_processo
INNER JOIN Unidade u ON u.cod_unidade  = M.COD_UNIDADE  
where 
not exists(select * from anexos a where a.num_proc_anexo = p.num_processo and a.ativo = 1) 
and not exists(select * from movimentacao m1 where m1.num_movimentacao= M.num_movimentacao and m1.motivo = 10 and m1.arquivado = 0) 
and ( not exists (select  * from distrib_vincjud  d2 where d2.num_processo = p.num_processo) 
or  p.num_processo in  (select  d3.num_processo from distrib_vincjud  d3  
                         where d3.num_processo = p.num_processo 
                         and d3.cod_servidor not in(select cod_servidor from servidor)
                         and d3.id_vinc in (select  max(d4.id_vinc) from distrib_vincjud d4 
                  where d4.num_processo = d3.num_processo and d4.data_vinc <= M.arq_data )))
and M.COD_UNIDADE in (select M.COD_UNIDADE   from movimentacao m2 where 
(m2.cod_ORIGEM_MOV = '26000181' or m2.cod_ORIGEM_MOV = '2600000X')and m2.num_processo = p.num_processo)
and p.tipo = 'J'
and  M.arq_data  >= '2011-08-01 00:00:00'AND M.arq_data  <='2011-08-31 23:00:00'
```

Comment: What do you mean by `allowing change m.arq_data and m2.arq_data values`?

Comment: select * FROM the_view WHERE m.arq_data = X AND m2.arq_data = Y

Comment: He probably meant allowing the two column to be variable

Answer (score 1):

View cannot take parameters. Implement it as table-valued udf instead (or stored procedure).

Comment: @celsowm, read up on UDFs here: http://www.extremeexperts.com/sql/articles/UDFFunctions.aspx

Comment: Another link with example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying you want to define your view to work with changing dates for conditions like `m2.arq_data BETWEEN '2011-08-01 00:00:00'AND '2011-08-31 23:00:00'` then it depends what your requirements are.

For instance if this date range will always be `between today and 31 days from now` then you could change this line to be something like this:

```
m2.arq_data BETWEEN GetDate() AND DATEADD (dd, 31, GetDate())
```

If the date range is not something fairly simple that can be defined generically using SQL then you might want to consider using a stored proc or a udf and passing it the date params.

Comment: Should be DATEADD(MM, 1, GETDATE()) ;)